# Best practices for fixing bugs in event stream processing

Tags: stream-processing, event-handling

We are working on an event driven system that works a streaming technology (eventhub/kinesis/kafka).  Imagine some system is generating events that are sent to the event stream. Then there are multiple diferent processors that are doing something different with the events and based on the events they update some internal state (persisted in DB). Question is what if one of the processor has bug and the persisted state in DB is therefore wrong. What are the best practices for recovering from these bugs?

PS: I kinda assume if the bug was on the event producer I would do some compensation events but what if one of processors (consumer) is wrong

Comment: This is almost impossible to answer without more specific information. In general, the best approach to dealing with bugs is to find and fix their cause. As a workaround when you have buggy behavior in some part of the system you can attempt to reset it to a known good state occasionally, for example copy state from another part of the system when you have reasons to suspect that you missed an event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A Bug!**

Fix the bug.

Otherwise the problem will manifest again.

**And it corrupted the database!!!**

Have you been maintaining good database hygiene?

- Backups
- Transaction logs
- Reconciliation with other systems
- Copies of events on the event stream

Then:

- If you have a known good backup, and all of the events that happened since. You could rebuild the database after having fixed the bug and swap over to that recomputed database.
- If you do not have a known good backup, but you do have a list of transactions you can at least identify the bad state and manually correct it. Just because it is in the database does not make it beyond manual modification. (Of course the modification should be scripted and tested).
- If you have comprehensive reconciliation, use it to guide your fixes.
- If the data is a copy from an upstream system, purge and resync, or verify and recover that data. This could be done manually by a Database tool, or through an automated batch process.

Otherwise - You are in a tough spot:

- No known good point to return to
- No knowledge of what that faulty processor did
- Nothing to reconcile the database with, so you cannot tell if there is a mismatch (assuming you fixed it).
- No Authoritative source.